# Cannot log in with Facebook: Samsung S8

Tags: bug, android-app

I keep getting a 'no email' error when trying to login with Facebook. This account I had to create with my Google account but I do not want to lose my reputation from the account I generated with my Facebook account. Can I transfer my reputation from the FB account to the Google account?

[image: Screen shot of login page.]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-G950U

  - OS Version: 7.0 (G950USQU1AQGL)

Comment: >`Can I transfer my reputation from the FB account to the Google account?`

You can request an account merge.

Comment: Can you login with the Facebook account (to Stack Exchange) using a web browser?